# Oracle PL/SQL How to call remote procedure (RPC) on commit

Tags: oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

Oracle PL/SQL How to call remote procedure (RPC) on commit.
Example: I have one table TABLE1 and insert into TABLE1 some rows and commit. I need call remote procedure on commit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure quite what you mean by a remote procedure, but if you want to do anything "on commit" then usually the best way is to create an AFTER trigger that calls DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT to perform the work.  The job is only performed if the transaction is committed, not if it rolls back.  The trigger would be something like:

```
create trigger call_rpc
after insert on table1
for each row
declare
   l_job number;
begin 
   dbms_job.submit( l_job, 'mypkg.run_rpc(:new.id);' );
end;
```

where `mypkg.run_rpc` is a procedure that does whatever you need to do.